# Unable to communicate with glue schema registry using iam roles for service accounts (IRSA)

Tags: spring, amazon-iam, aws-glue, amazon-eks, aws-msk

we use IAM roles for service accounts in EKS for secure resource access. Recently we are trying to adopt to MSK and glue schema registry.
sdk we are using is `aws-glue-schema-registry`.

while IRSA works as expected with other services like `secret manager` for instance we get this error when we try to connect with glue schema registry

```bash
software.amazon.awssdk.services.glue.model.AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::****************:assumed-role/NODE_ROLE/i-833fu7203a782371 is not authorized to perform: glue:GetSchemaByDefinition on resource: arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:****************:registry/schema-registry because no identity-based policy allows the glue:GetSchemaByDefinition action (Service: Glue, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 74269899-8eaf-48dc-831b-7j271209231j71)
```

**IAM PERMISSIONS**

```json
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "glue:*",
                "kafka:*",
                "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds",
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Sid": ""
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>msk-poc-with-schema-reg</artifactId>
    <version>2022.24.36</version>
    <name>msk-poc-with-schema-reg</name>
    <description>demo project for demo with glue</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR9</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.glue</groupId>
            <artifactId>schema-registry-serde</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.238</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/avro</sourceDirectory>

                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <stringType>String</stringType>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Glue Configuration**

```java
package com.kafka.gluedemo.config.msk;

import com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.serializers.GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaSerializer;
import com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.utils.AWSSchemaRegistryConstants;
import com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.utils.AvroRecordType;
import com.kafka.gluedemo.config.glue.GlueProperties;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
public class MskConfig {
    private final GlueProperties glueProperties;
    private final MskProperties mskProperties;

    public MskConfig(final GlueProperties glueProperties,
                     final MskProperties mskProperties) {
        this.glueProperties = glueProperties;
        this.mskProperties = mskProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties mskConfigProperties() {

        //producer config for MSK

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, mskProperties.getProducer().getBootstrapServers());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaSerializer.class.getName());

        props.put(AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.DATA_FORMAT, glueProperties.getDataFormat());
        props.put(AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.AWS_REGION, glueProperties.getRegion());
        props.put(AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.REGISTRY_NAME, glueProperties.getRegistryName());
        props.put(AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.AVRO_RECORD_TYPE, AvroRecordType.GENERIC_RECORD.getName());
        props.put(AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.SCHEMA_AUTO_REGISTRATION_SETTING, true);
        props.put(AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.SCHEMA_NAMING_GENERATION_CLASS, CustomAWSSchemaNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        return props;
    }

    @Bean("producer")
    public KafkaProducer<String, Object> kafkaProducer(final Properties mskConfigProperties) {
        return new KafkaProducer<String, Object>(mskConfigProperties);
    }
}
```

Comment: having the same problem were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: you might be running into the same issue described here https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-schema-registry/issues/68